# Sending data weekly to the server using POST

Tags: android, post, server, accelerometer

I am working on an accelerometer application. My application is saving data on local storage i.e. user's smartphone. I want to send it to the server, but I want to send it weekly. Is there any function that can be used to send the data automatically after a week.

I am using Android Studio for this. Sorry, I am new to this, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `WorkManager` architecture component to achieve it. Schedule a `PeriodicWorkRequest` as follows:

**Create Worker class:**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {

        // Send your data to server

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)
    }
}
```

**Schedule the Work:**

```
  PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new 
  PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 7, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                   .build();
  WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWork);
```

This creates a PeriodicWorkRequest to run periodically once every 7 days. You can also set some extra constraints like execute this task only if internet connection is available. This will execute the task once in 7 days and only if device has internet connection.

Comment: Say upload fails because no internet. If internet connection comes back after five minutes. Then do we have to wait seven days?

Comment: @greenapps `Then do we have to wait seven days? ` No. The PeriodicWorkRequest is guaranteed to run exactly one time during this interval (subject to contraints).  It may run immediately, at the end of the period, or any time in between so long as the other conditions are satisfied at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try AlarmManager

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Seconds, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);
```

also, create BroadcastReceiver that receive `pendingIntent`, if you have any question, pls comment below